# How to get other users call and conference call detail using Lync SDK

Tags: lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

How do i get other users call and conference call detail using Lync SDK.
I am interested to know to whom he is currently talking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ConversationManager to get a list of current Conversations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.conversationmanager.conversations_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt(v=office.14).aspx) Within each Conversation is a list of Participants. And within each Participant is a contact object which contains all the information about a contact.

There's no way to identify the active speaker though.

Answer (score 0):

For getting active speaker you can be used this code:

```
((AVModality) participant.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo]).StreamStateChanged += ...
```

Thats event handles for each participant when the audio/video stream changed state (active or no active).

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.audiovideo.streamstatechangedeventargs_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt_members.aspx